# auditctl - file being created on server

Tags: linux, security, apache-http-server, php

I have a situation which I need help with. I appreciate any feedback and help.

a file wp-signups.php is being created automatically in public_html. If I deleted the file, it is instantly recreated.

I setup auditctl, but I am having had time interpreting the log to see which script is created the file. From auditctl I get the pid and run the command

ausearch -f /path.../wp-signups.php

But in the results I don't see an actual script responsible for the file creation. Here is part from the response:

```
time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:02 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801902.799:297632): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801902.799:297632):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801902.799:297632): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:04 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801904.800:297634): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801904.800:297634): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801904.800:297634):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801904.800:297634): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:04 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801904.800:297636): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801904.800:297636): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801904.800:297636):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801904.800:297636): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:04 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801904.800:297637): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801904.800:297637):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801904.800:297637): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:06 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801906.800:297641): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801906.800:297641): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801906.800:297641):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801906.800:297641): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:06 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801906.801:297643): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801906.801:297643): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801906.801:297643):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801906.801:297643): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:06 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801906.801:297644): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801906.801:297644):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801906.801:297644): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:08 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801908.801:297646): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801908.801:297646): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801908.801:297646):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801908.801:297646): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:08 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801908.801:297648): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801908.801:297648): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801908.801:297648):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801908.801:297648): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:08 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801908.802:297649): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801908.802:297649):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801908.802:297649): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:10 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801910.802:297651): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801910.802:297651): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801910.802:297651):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801910.802:297651): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:10 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801910.802:297653): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801910.802:297653): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801910.802:297653):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801910.802:297653): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:10 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801910.802:297654): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801910.802:297654):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801910.802:297654): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:12 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801912.803:297656): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801912.803:297656): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801912.803:297656):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801912.803:297656): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:12 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801912.803:297658): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801912.803:297658): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801912.803:297658):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801912.803:297658): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:12 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801912.803:297659): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801912.803:297659):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801912.803:297659): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:14 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801914.804:297661): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801914.804:297661): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801914.804:297661):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801914.804:297661): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:14 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801914.804:297663): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801914.804:297663): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801914.804:297663):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801914.804:297663): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:14 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801914.804:297664): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801914.804:297664):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801914.804:297664): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:16 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801916.804:297666): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801916.804:297666): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801916.804:297666):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801916.804:297666): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:16 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801916.804:297668): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801916.804:297668): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801916.804:297668):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801916.804:297668): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:16 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801916.805:297669): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801916.805:297669):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801916.805:297669): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:18 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801918.805:297671): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801918.805:297671): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801918.805:297671):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801918.805:297671): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:18 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801918.805:297673): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801918.805:297673): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801918.805:297673):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801918.805:297673): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:18 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801918.805:297674): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801918.805:297674):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801918.805:297674): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:20 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801920.806:297676): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801920.806:297676): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801920.806:297676):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801920.806:297676): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:20 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801920.806:297678): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801920.806:297678): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801920.806:297678):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801920.806:297678): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:20 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801920.806:297679): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801920.806:297679):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801920.806:297679): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:22 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801922.807:297681): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801922.807:297681): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801922.807:297681):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801922.807:297681): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:22 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801922.807:297683): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801922.807:297683): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801922.807:297683):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801922.807:297683): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:22 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801922.807:297684): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801922.807:297684):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801922.807:297684): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:24 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801924.807:297686): item=1 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100444 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=DELETE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801924.807:297686): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=04gid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801924.807:297686):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801924.807:297686): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=1 a2=22b439f6ca900 items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=5y=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:24 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801924.808:297688): item=1 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 de00644 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE type=PATH msg=audit(1638801924.808:297688): item=0 name="/home/enotal1/public_html/" inode=15046856 dev=08:18 mode=0ogid=99 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT type=CWD msg=audit(1638801924.808:297688):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801924.808:297688): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=6 a0=7ffc885a4570 a1=241 a2=70772f6c items=2 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fone) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
---- time->Mon Dec  6 09:45:24 2021 type=PATH msg=audit(1638801924.808:297689): item=0 name="wp-signups.php" inode=15046885 dev=08:18 mode=0100644 ouid=ev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL type=CWD msg=audit(1638801924.808:297689):  cwd="/home/enotal1/public_html" type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1638801924.808:297689): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b439fe87c70 a1=124 a23=2b439f6ca900 items=1 ppid=26899 pid=6638 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgidtty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" key=(null)
```

Can someone please help me identify the script responsible for created that file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> But in the results I don't see an actual script responsible for the file creation. Here is part from the response:

Yes, because that script isn't being run as a standalone program – it is being run by a web server through FastCGI. The "php-fpm" that you're seeing is a long-running PHP FastCGI service; it handles many PHP requests in the same process.

> Can someone please help me identify the script responsible for created that file? Thank you.

You have the exact time when the HTTP request was made – search your webserver's access logs for that timestamp. At minimum they should contain the URL that was accessed.

You can additionally enable the same logging in PHP-FPM through its `access.log =` pool option (note: that's *not* a php.ini option). This will work like the webserver's access.log, but can additionally contain the actual PHP script path that was executed (which is useful if the original URL has gone through many layers of RewriteRules).